# Angular 2/4/5/6 how to get object property

Tags: angular, typescript, object

I have an api call, however I seem to be getting problems retrieving the properties in the object.

**step.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.stepService.getSteps().subscribe(appconfig => {
        console.log(appconfig); //this returns me an object
        console.log(appconfig.isstepcontactdisabled); // this gives me undefined
    }
}
```

**step.service.ts**

```
  getSteps(): Observable<Step> {
    return this.http.get<Step>(appConfig.apiBasePath + "appconfig").pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError),
    );
  }
```

**step.ts**

```
export interface Step {
  appconfig: Appconfig;
}

export interface Appconfig {
  isstepcontactdisabled: boolean;
  isstepdevicebranddisabled: boolean;
  issteppaymentinfodisabled: boolean;
  isstepservicetypedisabled: boolean;
}
```

Here are my results (console.log in step.component.ts, I'm getting undefined)

[image]

I tried getting the property using appconfig.isstepcontactdisabled and appconfig["isstepcontactdisabled"] but it is still shows as undefined. Could someone enlighten me? Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `appconfig.appconfig.isstepcontactdisabled`, or `appconfig['appconfig']['isstepcontactdisabled']`.

The object is kinda nested, thus you might have missed the `appconfig` property.

Try running `console.log(appconfig.appconfig.isstepcontactdisabled)` on it!

Comment: One word of advice though, if you are using Step.ts purely for typechecking, you might want to use an interface rather than class.